# How to implement SSL for an existing REST service in Java?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, ssl

I have REST services programmed in java. It also uses SpringBoot. How do I add SSL encryption to the REST service?

Comment: Is it a standalone app or deployed to an application server?

Comment: `stunnel` is a drop-in tool to add `S` to any `HTTP`. something you can work with?

Comment: with SpringBoot, I think it deploys to Wildfly. I then package into Docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setup a proxy server like `NGINX/APACHE` to proxy requests to REST service and configure SSL certificates on proxy.